# error message related to self.__dict__['__flags']:

Tags: python, tensorflow

In one program, there has something like this

```
if not FLAGS.save and FLAGS.name is None:
        output_dir = os.path.join(runs_dir, 'debug')
```

Running this python program gives me error messages such as, which is caused by the above code segment

```
File "train.py", line 54, in main
utils.set_dirs(hypes, tf.app.flags.FLAGS.hypes)
File "/home/AP5/tensorvision/utils.py", line 71, in set_dirs
if not FLAGS.save and FLAGS.name is None:
File "/devl/tensorflow/tf_0.12/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/flags.py", line 50, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: save
```

I checked the code for `__getattr__`,

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
"""Retrieves the 'value' attribute of the flag --name."""
if not self.__dict__['__parsed']:
  self._parse_flags()
if name not in self.__dict__['__flags']:
  raise AttributeError(name)
return self.__dict__['__flags'][name]
```

But I am not quite understand the line of code  `if name not in self.__dict__['__flags']:`, and how to fix the error message I get.

Comment: What is the type of `FLAGS`?

Comment: Did you actually provide a `save` flag?

Comment: It's unlikely that understanding that line will be useful for debugging your problem. `tf.app.flags.FLAGS` doesn't have a `save` attribute. The object happens to implement its attributes in an unusual way, but the object's attribute storage and retrieval mechanism doesn't appear to be relevant. The error lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change it to add whatever is missing from below

```
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_boolean('save', True,
                        """Whether or not to save.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('name', "some name",
                        """The name.""")

if not FLAGS.save and FLAGS.name is None:
    output_dir = os.path.join(runs_dir, 'debug')
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression `FLAGS.name is None` executes a `__getattr__` operation on the object/instance `FLAGS`.

`FLAGS` has an instance dictionary, accessed via `self.__dict__`

Within that instance dictionary is a key called `__flags`

The value of the `name` variable is not found in this `__flags` key.

Presumably `FLAGS` gets instantiated with various attributes and in this case, it seems that `name` is not being set properly. This is all I can deduce from the context you provided. If you want to provide more context I would recommend showing how the `FLAGS` object gets constructed.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation as well.